# In Horizontal List view builder how to use container without declaring height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

In container I am using list view builder, while I am using Axis.horizantal without declaring height of I am getting render box layout issue

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what are you expecting

Answer (score 0):

you can use the combination of SingleChildScrollView and Row to replicate the Behaviour of Listview with horizontal Scroll.

An example is mentioned below, this one worked for me.

> ```
> Container(
>   color: Colors.black,
>   child: SingleChildScrollView(
>     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
>     child: Row(
>       children: const [
>         Icon(Icons.phone),
>       ],
>     ),
>   ),
> ),
> ```

Comment: then  how to use my list in row

Comment: what do you have in your list??

Comment: if your are building your widget from a list you can use map to build it.